# Type bound for a function with return lifetime

Tags: rust

Consider the function

```
fn f(v: &[usize]) -> impl Iterator<Item = usize> + '_ {
    v.iter().cloned()
}
```

I want to write a generic function `g` which accepts any function with the same signature as `f`, and calls that function with various lifetimes. Is this possible?

---

**My attempt 1**: I naively wrote

```
fn g<F>(f: F)
where
    F: for<'a> Fn(&'a [usize]) -> (impl Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a) {}
```

but I got

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method return types, not in `Fn` trait return
```

---

**My attempt 2**: I tried to give `g` another type parameter for the specific iterator type:

```
fn g<F, I>(f: F)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = usize>,
    F: for<'a> Fn(&'a [usize]) -> I {}
```

I think this would work if the iterator were `'static`. But in this case I'd need `I` to be a higher kinded type with one lifetime parameter. Concretely, this `g` compiles but doesn't accept `f`.

---

**My attempt 3**: As above, but giving `g` a lifetime parameter to specialize `f`:

```
fn g<'a, F, I>(f: F)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a,
    F: Fn(&'a [usize]) -> I {}
```

This compiles and accepts `f`, but the body of `g` can only use `f` with the specific lifetime `'a`.

Comment: I can't think of a way of implementing exactly this in stable Rust.I think your options are either returning `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize> + '_>` from the function if you can take the dynamic dispatch overhead, or implementing a custom trait with a generic associated type, if you are fine using unstable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/jpg0pp/defining_a_fn_bound_with_generic_return_type_that/), I found a solution for the original interface (without a `Box`) using a helper trait:

```
fn f(v: &[usize]) -> impl Iterator<Item = usize> + '_ {
    v.iter().cloned()
}

trait Helper<'a> {
    type I: Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a;
    fn call(self, v: &'a [usize]) -> Self::I;
}
impl<'a, I, F> Helper<'a> for F
where
    I: Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a,
    F: Fn(&'a [usize]) -> I,
{
    type I = I;
    fn call(self, v: &'a [usize]) -> Self::I {
        self(v)
    }
}

fn g<F>(f: F)
where
    F: for<'a> Helper<'a>,
{
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    {
        let iter = f.call(&v);
        for i in iter {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    g(f)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Sven Marnach pointed out it could be done with a `Box` pointer.

```
fn f(v: &[usize]) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize> + '_> {
    Box::new(v.iter().cloned())
}

fn g<F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn(&[usize]) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize> + '_>
{
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    {
        let iter = f(&v);
        for i in iter {
            println!("{}", i);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    g(f)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really help. The lifetimes are still chosen by the caller of `g`. What we want is that `g` is free to call `f` with an arbitrary lifetime, and that the returned iterator is bound by that lifetime chosen inisde of `g`.

Comment: Maybe an example showing that weakness of variant 3 could help

Comment: Here you go: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=37e962afbc122a80cac096bc81ecacf7 (already using your proposal, which I think is actually completely equivalent to variant 3).

Comment: I edited the answer to match your comment for using the `Box` pointer.